# How to invoke Android emulator by using feature file in Karate Framework

Tags: karate

Am going to open Google URL in emulator when execute feature file in karate framework.
But i getting test case is failed due to following reason:

```
17:49:10.459 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593087505311 - poll attempt #20 
for port to be ready - localhost:58674
17:49:13.452 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
1 > POST http://localhost:58674/session
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 58
1 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Host: localhost:58674
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/1.8.0_181)
{"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"browserName":"android"}}}
```

---

## "Please provide me solution"

## Pre-condition: Appium Server and emulator is running.  and below is feature file.

Feature: Mobile automation

Background:

```
 * url 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'
   * configure driver = { type: 'android' }
   * def driverCaps = {"browserName": "chrome","newCommandTimeout":180, "platformVersion": "8.0", 
   "platformName": "Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554", "avd":"Nexus 6P API 26"}
   Scenario: Perform additional operation

  Given driver 'https://google.com'
  And input("input[name=q]", 'karate dsl')
  When submit().click("input[name=btnI]")
  # this may fail depending on which part of the world you are in !
  Then waitForUrl('https://github.com/intuit/karate')
```

Answer (score 2):

your `driverCaps` is unused as you have defined it after `configure`,

using the below snippet I was able to launch a chrome browser in Android Emulator.

```
Scenario: launch chrome in appium
* configure driver = 
"""
{ 
    type: 'android', 
    webDriverPath : "/wd/hub", 
    start: true, 
    httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }
}
"""
* def desiredConfig = 
"""
{
   "newCommandTimeout" : 300,
   "platformVersion" : "9.0",
   "platformName" : "Android",
   "connectHardwareKeyboard" : true,
   "deviceName" : "emulator-5554",
   "avd" : "Pixel2",
   "automationName" : "UiAutomator2",
   "browserName" : "Chrome"
  }
"""
* driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)"} }
* driver 'http://google.com'
* driver.input("//input[@name='q']", 'karate dsl')
```

**Note:**

> if you are facing any chrome driver issue please refer : [chromedriver with Appium](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md#chromedriver)
> currently only xpath locator are working so try with xpath locators

Comment: Thank you. we followed same instruction getting following erros:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:4723 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect, options: {type=android, webDriverPath=http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub, start=false, httpConfig={readTimeout=120000}, target=null, webDriverSession={desiredCapabilities={newCommandTimeout=300, platformVersion=10.0, platformName=Android, connectHardwareKeyboard=true, deviceName=emulator-5554, avd=Pixel_2_API_29, automationName=UiAutomator2, browserName=Chrome}}}

Comment: I have modified the `start` flag to `true` in the answer now so that karate starts appium server for you. else you can try starting it manually then run your code

Comment: Thank so much.Its working fine.i was facing chrome driver issue then i set following capab. working fine - "browserName" : "Chrome" ,
   "chromedriverExecutable" : "C:/Users/ABC/Downloads/chromedriver_win32_2/chromedriver.exe"

Comment: Sorry,i facing one more issue when executing below script - driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)"} }
* driver 'http://google.com'
* driver.input("//input[@name='q']", 'karate dsl') - getting error like - Encountered interna
l error running command: NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
17:15:23.990 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] WARN com.intuit.karate - http response code: 500 - Please suggest how to write script in karate. is it work normal xpath written in selenium?